# golang - string permutation - slice bounds out of range

Tags: string, go, permutation, indexoutofboundsexception

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/pJvK2PADtG) is the Go Playground code for this problem.

I am trying to write a golang string permutation using recursion.
The permutation function takes two arguments, prefix which is an empty string (`""`) and `str` which is "`abc`". The code is below

```
func main() {
    str := "abc"
    perm("", str)
}

func perm(prefix string, str string) {
    n := len(str)
    fmt.Println(n)
    if n == 0 {
        fmt.Println(prefix)
    } else {
        for i := 0; i < n; n++ {
            perm(prefix+str[i:i+1], str[0:i]+str[(i+1):n])
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I am shown 3,2,1,0 for the value of n as expected.
I successfully get "`abc`" but then I get a "`panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range`" error.

It never shows the second round of 3,2,1,0 so it doesn't even get to the `b` combinations. I feel like if an error would occur is when it gets to the `c` portion of the string but since it doesn't even get to the `b` portion, I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Note: always use formatted code (see the button "Format" on the playground page)

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
for i := 0; i < n; n++ {
                   ^^^
                    ?
```

Replace `n` by `i`, which is supposed to go from `0` to `n-1`.

[Resulting playground](https://play.golang.org/p/b_QNRTIaZe).

Comment: Ahhh I can't believe I missed that! Thank you, I was so focused on the recursion line because that's what the compiler was telling me...